# Does a polyfill exist for getDestinationInsertionPoints?

Tags: polymer

I've come across a situation where it would be helpful to know whether a given node has been distributed into a `content` node. There's a native Shadow DOM function node.getDestinationInsertionPoints() that's very helpful for this purpose, but I don't see a version of this in the polyfill world.

I can work around the need for this by doing my own inspection of a node's parent chain, but it'd be nicer to rely on the standard (?) getDestinationInsertionPoints() function. Does -- or will -- the Shadow DOM polyfill support this in older browsers?

Comment: Good question. Mind filing an issue against the SD polyfill and posting it here so others can follow the conversation?

Comment: @ebidel: Done. https://github.com/Polymer/ShadowDOM/issues/417

Comment: For those interested: the above issue appears to have now been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ShadowDOM polyfill should now support a polyfilled version of `getDestinationInsertionPoints()`. This particular change should be available in 0.3.x: https://github.com/polymer/polymer/releases

Comment: Yes, I noted above that it had been fixed. Forgot to make that comment into an answer that I could mark as correct.